# How to utilize htmlspecialchars within echo

Tags: php

You can visit this link for an example of my promlem :      http://jflaugher.mystudentsite.net/cmweb241/cmweb241_lab2.html

Everything is working correctly, except that I am having problems utilizing the htmlspecialchars in my echo.  I am wanting the entity to show up in the echo and not the html character.  I have tried placing the htmlspecialchars within the echo, but then the paragraph tags shows up.  How do I utilize the htmlspecialchar in the echo, and display the echo in a paragraph tag?  I have been at this for some time and have gotten no where, as I am very new to PHP.

For example, when I enter a '&', I get that echoed back.  Instead of the '&', I want the entity &amp to be echoed.

```
 <?php
  $username = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", $_POST['username']));
  $password = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", $_POST['password']));
  $comment = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", $_POST['comment']));

  echo  "<p> Your Username is: $username .</p> ";
  echo " <p>Your Password is: $password . </p>";
  echo " <p>Your Comment was: $comment . </p>";

 ?>
```

Comment: where are you viewing this output? in a browser? in an html context, the browser will show the rendered character, not the entity you embedded in the text. try a 'view source', which'd show the entities.

Comment: Please be more clear on the input and the expected output. I have no idea where you think the problem is. Also, why are you replacing quotes?

Comment: @MarcB I am viewing the echo in a browser.  When I enter a '&' for example, I get echoed back a '&'.  I instead want the enity &amp; to be echoed.

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean by this: "I am wanting the entity to show up in the echo and not the html character". Provide an example input and the correct output you want to get.

Comment: That's normal. a bare `&` is generally always rendered as a `&` by browsers, even though technically it should be treated as a broken entity. but if you do `echo '&amp;'`, the browser will render a `&`, but view-source will show you `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this means:

> > I am wanting the entity to show up in the echo and not the html character.

Are you saying that you want the entity to be displayed in your web page?  htmlspecialchars *is* converting the characters to entities, but a browser will display those entities as the characters they represent.

If you want to actually *see* the entities in your browser, you can double-escape the values:

```
$username = htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", 
                             $_POST['username'])));
```

But I don't really think that's the purpose of the exercise you're doing.

Comment: Say I enter a '&' into the textarea.  The echo gives me the '&', but I am instead wanting it to be the enitity &amp;.

Comment: No, the echo gives you the entity `&amp;`. Your browser renders that as `&`. If you view source on your webpage, you will see that the `&`, `<`, and `>` it's displaying are entities in the source.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Instead of the & showing up, I wanted the entity to show up.  I guess I asked the question wrong.

Comment: No worries. I guess it would have been a bit clearer if you had said "I want the entity to display in the browser (so that I can see `&amp;` in the browser instead of `&`" or something like that, but you clarified what you meant and that's what matters. :)

Answer (score 2):

Say you enter `&`.
`htmlspecialchars` will turn this into `&amp;`.
`&amp;` is the HTML entity for `&`, so viewing the result in a browser displays `&`.

This is the normal purpose of `htmlspecialchars`, it preserves the *visible character* by escaping it for the medium (HTML) appropriately.

If you want `&` to turn into a visible `&amp;`, the browser will need to receive `&amp;amp;`. Apply `htmlspecialchars` twice to do that:

```
htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']))
```

Maybe [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) helps you to understand the topic better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the entities, you could apply `htmlspecialchars()` twice and it will turn all the `&` in `&amp;` to `&amp;amp;` and thus the entity itself will be displayed.

Another method is wrapping the output in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: Yes, I want to display the entity instead.  I am having problems with how to utilize the htmlspecialchars twice.

Comment: Basically, what deceze said, I just didn't write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<?php
$string = "<tag>&";

$string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
print $string;
```

It will print:

`&lt;tag&gt;&amp;`

[How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)